# Understanding a limiting procedure

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus, continuity

Say I have a function $f(x,y)$ that is defined for all $x \leq 0$ except at a single point $x=x_0 \neq 0.$  There exists one representation of the function in the domain $x < x_0$ and another representation of the function for $x_0< x \leq 0.$

Now consider another function $g(y)$ which I have and would like to see as the limit of $f(x,y)$ as $x \rightarrow 0.$

**My question is:**

If I take the limit as $x \rightarrow 0$ of the representation of the function $f(x,y)$ in the interval $x<x_0,$ would I expect to recover $g(y)$? My thought was initially no because the limit of $x \rightarrow 0$ is not in this representation’s domain of validity but I seem to obtain the correct result.

That is,

$$\lim_{x\rightarrow 0} \,\,f(x,y)|_{x<x_0} = g(y).$$

Am I being naive or is there a simple reason for that?

(This is something that came up in a physics project)

Thanks!

Comment: It makes no sense to use the piece of f defined with $x<x_0<0$ to take a limit as $x\to 0$. It could happen by coincidence that the formal calculation of this limit using an expression for this part of f which has a larger domain gives the same result, though.

Comment: @Ian Yes,I thought so too as written in my question, but the limiting result is correct. So my conclusions where either it's just a coincidence or the two representations either side of $x=x_0$ are the same.

Comment: @Ian I see, so do you mean to say that the representation for $x_0 <x \leq 0$ might simply coincide with that for $x<x_0$?

Comment: They might not be exactly the same but still agree in the limit $x \to 0$.